# Android usb host- otg detection

Tags: android

How to detect that android device having otg compatibility or not

I am using below code :

`context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_USB_HOST);`

It is always returning true for non-otg android devices

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does not always work, some kind of a bug.

Connect a usb device through otp and then in app use the UsbManager system service and enumerate through attached USB devices :

```
 mUsbManager = (UsbManager) mApplicationContext.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
 HashMap<String, UsbDevice> devlist = mUsbManager.getDeviceList();
 if(!devlist.isEmpty()){
    // Supports usb host...
 } else {
    // Does not supports usb host...
 }
```

Unfortunately, hardware usb device is required for this approach, I haven't found any other reliable software check to confirm it.

Hope it helps !

Comment: I want to check without usb cable on Button onclick event

Comment: Actually, Google knows nothing about ANDROID_FEATURE_HARDWARE_USB_HOST,   So, I doubt whether we can check it, may be there is a way (for rooted device) I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

This solution always work for API level 24 and above:

**Step 1** - Ask permission for using the secondary storage:

```
StorageManager storageManager = (StorageManager) getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
     StorageVolume primaryVolume = storageManager.getPrimaryStorageVolume(); // This will gives primary storage like internal storage
     List<StorageVolume> lstStorages = storageManager.getStorageVolumes(); // it will gives all secondary storage like SDCrad and USb device list
     for (int i = 0; i < lstStorages.size(); i++) {
         Intent intent = lstStorages.get(i).createAccessIntent(null); // null pass for get full access of storage
         startActivityForResult(intent, 6000);
     }
}
```

**Step 2** - After permission is granted:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (requestCode == 6000 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         Uri treeUri = data.getData();
         DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri); //List of all documents files of secondary storage
         List<DocumentFile> lstChildren = Arrays.asList(documentFile.listFiles());
         getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(treeUri, FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION); // It will not ask permission for every time
         for (DocumentFile documentFile1 : lstChildren) {
             getAllFiles(documentFile1);
         }
     }
}
```

**Step 3** - Get all files:

```
private void getAllFiles(DocumentFile documentFile) {
    DocumentFile[] files;
    files = documentFile.listFiles();
    for (DocumentFile file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            getAllFiles(file);
        } else {
            lstFiles.add(new UsbFileModel(documentFile, file.getUri()));
        }
    }
}
```