# Is there any way to calculate USB Storage size using tree uri in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to find total and used size of USB storage with the help of Tree Uri, i already get read and write Uri permission.

Comment: Can you share the code of how you read data using Uri?

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260552/android-usb-host-otg-detection/58993150#58993150 @Mahdi-Malv
I have already posted answer, how to read data from uri

Comment: If you can find that storage in getExternalFilesDirs() you can use the classic File.getSoragespace(). (Or what ever it is called).

Comment: Google for getAllocatedBytes().

Comment: getExternalFilesDirs() gives me only one storage directory which is internal storage,

Comment: what i want is total size of OTG (USB) storage using Storage Access Framework

Comment: any one have any idea?